# openSSL: how to initialize keys for public key encryption?

Tags: c, linux, ssl, openssl, public-key-encryption

For using openSSL API for public key encryption, how is the key (public & private) initialized in a C program, given private key in *.key file format, and public key in *.pem file format:

```
 EVP_PKEY *key;
 /* How is key initialized ?
  */
  ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(key);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
        EVP_PKEY *pkey;
        FILE *f = fopen("<path for your PEM or DER encoded key>", "rb");
        if (f == NULL){
                // error handling...
        }
    //if your key is PEM encoded use this
        pkey = PEM_read_PUBKEY(f, NULL, NULL, NULL); // pkey now contains the pubKey. 
    //We are passing NULL to the others parameters because we dont need password to read a public key

    //if your key is DER encoded use this
        pkey = d2i_PUBKEY_fp(f, NULL);

        if (pkey == NULL){
                // error handling...
        }
```

I didnt test but should work.

Comment: This stores private keys, what about public keys, and how are they initialized using the files as mentioned in the question ?

Comment: <code>
EVP_PKEY *pkey;
        FILE *f = fopen("<path for your PEM or DER encoded key>", "rb");
        if (f == NULL){
                // error handling...
        }
 //if your key is PEM encoded use this
        pkey = PEM_read_PUBKEY(f, NULL, NULL, NULL); // pkey now contains the pubKey. 
 //We are passing NULL to the others parameters because we dont need password to read a public key

 //if your key is DER encoded use this
        pkey = d2i_PUBKEY_fp(f, NULL);

        if (pkey == NULL){
                // error handling...
        }
</code>
I didnt test but should work.

Comment: .key is just the extension, not the encoding type...
Im also a beginner, but i believe that an .key extension mean that the certificate is PEM encoded.
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions